# Server error 500 when accessing deployed springboot-vaadin app on Google Cloud

Tags: java, spring, google-cloud-platform, vaadin

Please can somebody help with this problem? I am new to Google Cloud and my deployed springbboot - vaadin app on Google Cloud says server error 500 when accessing via browser.

Context:

- spring boot driven vaadin app in jar format
- google cloud dependencies added to maven
- spring security embedded in app with encrypted credentials in MySql db
- app was deployed via Google Cloud CLI
- service account in google cloud created - maybe missing some permissions

Error reporting in google cloud says this error:

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://clouddebugger.googleapis.com/v2/controller/debuggees/register

I studied a lot about this issue, but maybe main reason of this error is not clear for me. Why any security solution for access for public users is needed from google cloud? ... I supposed, that this is solved by spring boot security on the app side and that app will have a public access without any restrictions from google cloud side. As I say - I probably miss concept of this whole. So please can me somebody explain this and help with solving that exception? Thank you very much.

...

- Cloud Run ... this service seems to be disabled
- App Engine ... this service is running, but the "instance summary" section seems to be empty ... however by the logs and usage of app.yaml it seems this is intended to run on App Engine (I am sorry - I only followed the steps from this manuals - I have no experience with Google Cloud platform) ... app.yaml contains onle one single row -> "runtime: java11"
- I followed these manuals before:

  - book: Building Modern Web Apps with Spring Boot and Vaadin
  - web: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/production/cloud-providers/google
- Certain steps (... and some of log records from console) were these:

  - in Intellij Idea (Run Configuration) ... package appengine:deploy -Pproduction
  - in console ... generally log records about building backend and frontend
  - [INFO] Staging the application to: D:<APP-NAME>\target\appengine-staging
  - [INFO] Detected App Engine app.yaml based application.
  - okt 14, 2022 4:22:32 AM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.operations.GcloudRunner run
  - INFO: submitting command: C:\Users\Ján\AppData\Local\google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk\bin\gcloud.cmd app deploy --project
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: Services to deploy:
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: descriptor:                  [D:<APP-NAME>\target\appengine-staging\app.yaml]
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: source:                      [D:<APP-NAME>\target\appengine-staging]
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: target project:              []
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: target service:              [default]
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: target version:              [20221014t042237]
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: target url:                  [https://.lm.r.appspot.com]
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: target service account:      [App Engine default service account]
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: Beginning deployment of service [default]...
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: #============================================================#
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: #= Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 =#
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: #============================================================#
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: File upload done.
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: Updating service [default]...
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: ...done.
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: Setting traffic split for service [default]... done.
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: Deployed service [default] to [https://.lm.r.appspot.com]
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: You can stream logs from the command line by running:
  - [INFO] GCLOUD:   $ gcloud app logs tail -s default
  - [INFO] GCLOUD: To view your application in the web browser run:
  - [INFO] GCLOUD:   $ gcloud app browse
  - [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  - [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
  - [INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
- ... and theses are the last rows from Logs Explorer:

  - 2022-10-14 02:35:29.389 INFO 10 --- [ main]  : Started    - Application in 10.057 seconds (JVM running for 11.18)
  - 2022-10-14 02:35:29.476 INFO 10 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
  - 2022-10-14 02:35:29.477 INFO 10 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
  - 2022-10-14 02:35:29.478 INFO 10 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Completed initialization in 1 ms
  - 2022-10-14 02:35:29.524 INFO 10 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] c.v.f.s.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration : Vaadin is running in production mode.
    Exceeded hard memory limit of 256 MB with 265 MB after servicing 0 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class in app.yaml.
    [start] 2022/10/14 02:35:30.579484 Quitting on terminated signal

Comment: Could you check this: https://martinelli.ch/how-to-deploy-a-vaadin-application-to-google-cloud-app-engine/

Comment: Wher exactly did you deploy the app? App Engine, Cloud Run?

Comment: Please also checkout the Log Explorer and post the logs in the question

Comment: Hello SImon. Thanks so much for your concern. Your page looks great and is useful - I study it carefully. Next I am sending the answers to your questions ...